# CakePHP DbAcl::check() - Failed ACO node lookup in permissions check. Node references even though permissions exists

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

Hallo CakePHP developers.

I get the following error

> 2022-11-09 07:30:02 Warning: Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ACO node lookup in permissions check. Node references:
>
> ```
> Aro: Array
> (
>    [Platforms] => Array
>         (
>             [id] => 8
>             [company_id] => 26
>    ...
> ```
>
> Aco: controllers/Documents/download in [/var/www/vhosts/ecozins.de/httpdocs/hiver.finandu.de/vendor/cakephp/acl/src/Model/Table/PermissionsTable.php, line 91]

> Error: [Cake\Http\Exception\ForbiddenException] You are unautharised to access this page
> Request URL: /api/v1/documents/download/8869

I have three different platforms accessing methods and the issue occurs only in one of them and only the download function.

I checked my permissions and I do have them :(

Aco-Table

| id | parent_id | model | foreygn_key | alias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 | NULL | NULL | downlaod |

Aro-Table

| id | parent_id | model | foreygn_key | alias |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | 8 | Roles.6.Plattform-API |

Aro-Aco-Table

| id | aro_id | aco_id | _create | _read | _update | _delete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I also ran `cake acl_extras aco_sync`. But no changes occure since everything is up to date.

I also set up an identical system locally and there works fine. how???

I would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! I was concentrating just on the "broken" function.
Once I looked at the whole acos table closely I found out that the table displayed a function that was deleted in the code.
That nonexistent function had the same lft & rght values as the download function. Thus resulting in conflicts.